# Quadtree UV mapping texture

Tags: uv-mapping, heightmap, level-of-detail, quadtree, planet

I need help coming up with dynamic uv values (general formula) so that my texture looks continuous through all levels of my quadtree. level 0-1 works perfectly, level 1 subdivision looks great. but continuing to level 2 and onwards is where I realized my current method isn’t going to work. I need to come up with UV values unique to each quad at different levels.

here is a working example of my code: https://codepen.io/miguel007/pen/KKeMxQY?editors=0011

line 233 in the createLodChildQuads function is where I’m doing the UV modification.

Move the red player to activate Quadtree levels.
Control the red player (W,A,S,E,R,F)

level 0

[image]

level 1

[image]

level 2

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the default texture coordinates (0, 0)-(1, 1) for every plane geometry you create. You'll need to modify your code to give distinct texture coordinates to each child quad, or modify your shader to use world space position rather than texture coordinate attributes as the sample point to use for looking up into your texture.

Comment: Want to edit your question to show and describe the problem you're grappling with now? That gives it better visibility than sitting in a comment.

Comment: @DMGregory see the updated edit.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out the answer to this problem 4 days ago.

pseudo code

````js
//this allows for the correct scaling of each mesh uv for any level.
var scaling = currentMeshDimensions/rootMeshDimensions
var u_ = u * scaling 
var v_ = v * scaling 

// function to normalize input 0-1
function norm(val, max, min) { return (val - min) / (max - min); }

var wp = currentMesh.getWorldPosition()
var xn = norm(wp.x,rootMeshDimensions/2,-rootMeshDimensions/2)
var yn = norm(wp.y,rootMeshDimensions/2,-rootMeshDimensions/2)

var n = scaling/2

u = u_ + (xn-n)
v = v_ + (yn-n)

```
````

Comment: This answer would be even better if you briefly explained how this code solves your problem, so a future reader can learn from your strategy, even if their code isn't identical.